# How to store list in viewstate so that there is no data loss and when I try to add new list On Add Button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

On Save button click only one row is creating I want to each new row each Save button click.

// game = (List)(ViewState["newGame"]);
I tried like this but error is showing please help me.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindGridList();

    }
    protected List<Game> GetGameList()
    {
        List<Game> game = new List<Game>();
        Game lstGames = new Game("Counter Strike", "FPS", "20");

        game.Add(lstGames);
        lstGames = new Game("Fifa 19", "TPP", "50");
        game.Add(lstGames);
        lstGames = new Game("GTA V", "TPP", "45");
        game.Add(lstGames);
        lstGames = new Game("Apex Legends", "TPP", "20");
        game.Add(lstGames);
        lstGames = new Game("Jurrasic World", "3D", "100");
        game.Add(lstGames);
        lstGames = new Game("Tressure Hunt", "3D", "100");
        game.Add(lstGames);
        lstGames = new Game("X Man Origin", "TPP", "100");
        game.Add(lstGames);

       // ViewState["newGame"] = game;

        return game;

    }

    protected void BindGridList()
    {

        PriceList.DataSource = GetGameList();
        PriceList.DataBind();
    }


    protected void OnAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtGameName.Visible = true;
        txtGameCategory.Visible = true;
        txtGamePrice.Visible = true;
        btnSave.Visible = true;
        Update.Visible = true;
        btnUpdate.Visible = false;

    }

    protected void OnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtGameName.Visible = false;
        txtGameCategory.Visible = false;
        txtGamePrice.Visible = false;
        btnUpdate.Visible = false;
        Update.Visible = false;
        btnSave.Visible = false;

        string txtName = txtGameName.Text;
        string txtCategory = txtGameCategory.Text;
        string txtPrice = txtGamePrice.Text;

        List<Game> game = new List<Game>();

       // game = (List<Game>)(ViewState["newGame"]);
        game = GetGameList();
       // ViewState["newGame"] = game;

        Game lstNewGame = new Game(txtName, txtCategory, txtPrice);
        game.Add(lstNewGame);

        PriceList.DataSource = game;
        PriceList.DataBind();


    }
}
public class Game
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public Game(string name, string category, string price)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Category = category;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
```

}

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.